# DOMParser injects DOM but does not apply css stylesheets once injected?

Tags: javascript, dom, domparser

I have a little testcase over at:

http://jsfiddle.net/9xwUx/1/

The code boils down to the following (given a node with id "target"):

```
var string = '<div class="makeitpink">this should be pink, but is not</div>';
var parser = new DOMParser();
var domNode = parser.parseFromString(string,"text/xml");
document.getElementById("target").appendChild(domNode.firstChild);
```

If you run the testcase, and then inspect the target node via firebug/chrome web inspector and select any node within the body tag of jsfiddle's iframe, and do "edit as HTML", add a random charachter anywhere as a string [not an attribute to a domnode, to be clear], and "save", the style is applied. but not before that.
To say that i'm confused is an understatement.

Can anybody please clarify what is going on here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can change the mime type to `text/html` and do the following:

```
var parser = new DOMParser()
var doc = parser.parseFromString(markup, 'text/html')
return doc.body.firstChild
```

I didn't test on every browser but it works on Chrome and Firefox. I don't see any reason it wouldn't work elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

a bit late, but the reason is that you have parsed these using the `text/xml` option, which means that the results are XML nodes, which don't have CSS applied to them. When you right-click and go "edit as HTML" the browser reinterprets them as HTML and the change in the element will cause a redraw, reapplying the CSS.

I've been parsing my using the relatively hack-ish, yet definitely working method of creating a temporary element and manipulating the innerHTML property, making the browser do the parsing instead:

```
var temp = document.createElement("div")
//assuming you have some HTML partial called 'fragment'
temp.innerHTML = fragment
return temp.firstChild
```

Which you've noted in your jsfiddle. Basically it boils down to the output of the `DOMParser` being an instance of `XMLDocument` when you use the `text/xml` option.